# Checking if an item is contained in a ManyToManyField (django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

So I have a ManyToManyField relationship between Item1 and Item2. On a webpage, I want to display one of two messages based on whether the two items are connected or not. I'm just not sure how to query my exact item using the {% if %} template tag.

Roughly what I'm looking for is

```
{% if Item1 is connected to Item2 %} Display Message1
{% else %} Display Message2 {% endif %}
```

Any tips on how I'd get this done?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    eventList = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank="TRUE", null="TRUE", related_name='event_set+')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: We'll need at least the model definitions

Comment: There, sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It still not clear to me what object you want to see if connected to other but if you want to know if a user is in an specific event you can do it like this:

```
{% if event in user.eventList.all %} 
Display Message1
{% else %} 
Display Message2 
{% endif %}
```

You can use operator `in` in `if` conditions in modern django versions.

Hope this helps!